# Error in Android "SuperNotCalledException:Activity did not call through to super.OnCreate()"

Tags: android

> uncaught handler:thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   android.app.SuperNotCalledException:Activity did not call through to
>   super.OnCreate()

My Code is:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;


                Settings.System.putInt(this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

                // Post an intent to reload
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
                //intent.putExtra("state",! isEnabled);//Call ON
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                intent.putExtra("state", isEnabled);
                                                                                           this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);


}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 6):

add below code in manifest of corresponding activity

```
  android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

This issue happen with 8.0 version with Activity full screen and dialog activity

Comment: Had the same issue with Android 8.0. Setting the screenOrientation to fullSensor fixed it. (For whatever reason it does not work with "portrait" mode).

Comment: Yes fullSesor works, but then orientation doesn't remain portrait, I want to force it to portrait. Can you help? @Manuel