# Start activity from service isn't working (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service, touch-event

I created an overlay "always on top button", which is a service `HUD`, and I can't start an activity `screen` from  there, it gives the error: `"Unfortunately App has stopped"`. In the beginning, all I used to know if there was any `TouchEvent`was a toast, and that toast was created, but it was created several times, so I don't know if it gives that error because this code, which is on `TouchEvent` body , is repeated several times too.
here is my code:

```
public class HUD extends Service implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener {
Button mButton;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //mView = new HUDView(this);
    
    
    mButton = new Button(this);
    mButton.setId(1);
    mButton.setText("Button");
    mButton.setClickable(true);
    mButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    
    
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
                    PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.setTitle("Load Average");
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mButton, params);
    
    
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mButton != null)
    {
        ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mButton);
        mButton = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getX()<mButton.getWidth() & event.getY()>0)
    {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Overlay button event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this my toast
    Intent i = new Intent();                                                //this is my new acivity (intent)
    i.setClass(HUD.this, screen.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    HUD.this.stopSelf();
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.exit(1);
    return false;
}

}
```

So my question is, is this code on `TouchEvent` body being repeated several times? If it is, is that the cause of the error?

log cat:

```
07-20 22:11:06.962: I/Choreographer(1620): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on      its main thread.
07-20 22:11:08.062: D/AndroidRuntime(1620): Shutting down VM
07-20 22:11:08.062: W/dalvikvm(1620): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity    {com.example.screenshot/com.example.screenshot.screen} did not call through to super.onCreate()
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-20 22:11:08.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1620):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

screen.java:

```
public class screen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Made it", 0).show();
finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Try adding `return;` after `finish();`

Answer (score 5):

See [android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

```
Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(), screen.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(i);
```

You error seems to be inside `screen` activity. There are many thread which might help to figure out the error that you are getting for the activity:

[Error in Android "SuperNotCalledException:Activity did not call through to super.OnCreate()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260576/error-in-android-supernotcalledexceptionactivity-did-not-call-through-to-super)

[android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity did not call through to super.onStop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397020/android-app-supernotcalledexception-activity-did-not-call-through-to-super-onst)

**Update**

The error is because you haven't called: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your `screen` activity's `onCreate()`. That should be the first thing to be called in `onCreate()`. Do something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //.... other stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you post the logcat ?

Comment: i'll post it on  the question

Comment: If you see the error, you error is in `com.example.screenshot.screen` class. So do you have a `screen.java` activity? Can you post the code?

Comment: done, is a simple code, so I don't think that `screen`class is the problem

Comment: I think `screen` class is seems to be the problem. It is not calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` inside the `onCreate()`. Also just curious that why are you calling `onFinish()` in the `onCreate()`? if you just want to finish the activity as soon as you have created, then calling `finish()` is okay.

Comment: now isn't working on my 2.3.7 android version butits working on 4.0.0, I can upload the log if you want to

Comment: Sure. Please do add the recent Log .